# submitting message Django-Newsletter

Tags: django, logging, newsletter, handlers

(I'm new at django) I just installed django-newsletter app (https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-newsletter-dokterbob/) and when I try to submit using:

```
python manage.py runjob submit
```

I get:

```
No handlers could be found for logger
```

What is this error mean? and what should I do?
And I find it strange that I didn't set up SMTP or something (it isn't mentioned in the doc) should I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this issue, i have the same issue, and by submitting the submission and then run the above command will send the newsletters. https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter/issues/10

Comment: I'm having the same issue (django 1.10.3) and has nothing to do with the issue mentioned in the above comment. All that speak about is hitting the submit button before running the python manage.py runjob submit. . .Anyone else have a suggestion?